# How to make Kubernetes service load balance based on client IP instead of NGINX reverse proxy IP

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, web-applications, session-affinity

I have configured NGINX as a reverse proxy with web sockets enabled for a backend web application with multiple replicas. The request from NGINX does a `proxy_pass` to a Kubernetes service which in turn load balances the request to the endpoints mapped to the service. I need to ensure that the request from a particular client is proxied to the same Kubernetes back end pod for the life cycle of that access, basically maintaining session persistence.

Tried setting the `sessionAffinity: ClientIP` in the Kubernetes service, however this does the routing based on the client IP which is of the NGINX proxy. Is there a way to make the Kubernetes service do the affinity based on the actual client IP from where the request originated and not the NGINX internal pod IP ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an option with Nginx. Or rather it's not an option with anything in userspace like this without a lot of very fancy network manipulation. You'll need to find another option, usually an app-specific proxy rules in the outermost HTTP proxy layer.